# What is the algebraic formula to generate a decimal number of the form 10001000100010001... Examples below.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, power-series

examples:

To generate 1000100010001 we can use ((10^8 + 1) x 10001)
To generate 10001000100010001 we can use ( ((10^8 + 1) x 10001) x 10000 + 1 ).

This way how i can generate for any given string?

Comment: why not use $(1000)^*$

Comment: Presumably OP wants an algebraic formula, not a regular expression to match a string. @coffeemath

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The OP's use of the star notation seems to imply OP was looking for regular expressions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes. you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want
the $n$-digit number $a$
repeated $m$ times,
this is
$a+10^na+10^{2n}a...+10^{(m-1)n}a
=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} 10^{kn}a=a\dfrac{10^{mn}-1}{10^n-1}
$
since this is just
a standard geometric sum.

In your case,
$a=1000, n=4$
so this is
$a\dfrac{10^{mn}-1}{10^n-1}
=1000\dfrac{10^{4m}-1}{9999}
$.

Comment: The examples given have $a=1$, with $m=4$ or $5$ respectively.